# Integrating Duo MFA with OpenVPN Access Server

Tags: openvpn, authentication

I've been able to integrate Duo so that I get a push request on my iPhone when logging into the WebUI; however, this is not quite what I was looking for.

When I actually request access to the VPN via the application (I use macOS) using my autologin profile (or any profile) I want it to send a push request for authentication.

Is this possible?

Comment: Not likely. There's nothing in the OpenVPN protocol to support this sort of thing. And you're looking at the wrong place for putting 2FA anyway.

Comment: Well, you made quite a few assumptions, @MichaelHampton. In addition, this appears to be a fairly popular approach: https://duo.com/docs/openvpn

Comment: Huh, well I suppose that's one way to do it.